# AMP Test error when access from canonical HTML page, but test directly AMP url is valid. Why?

Tags: amp-html

I always have an error in [AMP Test](https://search.google.com/test/amp?hl=en) from canonical HTML pages.

But curiously, there are no error when I test AMP url directly.

[This is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LslSp.gif)

[This](https://ryota-mizumaki.com/products/Blazing-Fast-Blog/about_blog) is the url I tested. (This is blog articles written by Japanese.)

In canonical page, there is a link tag in head.

**article.html**

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://ryota-mizumaki.com/amp/products/Blazing-Fast-Blog/about_blog" data-react-helmet="true">
```

And in AMP page, there is a canonical link tag in head.

**article.amp.html**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://ryota-mizumaki.com/products/Blazing-Fast-Blog/about_blog">
```

In the canonical page, I redirect `/amp` direstory access to non amp page because when user have cache of my page, I don't wanna show AMP page but wanna show PWA page.

I think this redirection is the cause of this mulfunction.

I want to know which Google's crawler can validly access PWA page to AMP page or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to [validate your amp page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/validate)?

Comment: @R. M. Did you find solution for the issue ?

Comment: @Muhammed Nope. I still don't know why, but in Search Console, it seems there are no error in this website so I decided to do not care.